# Divide training data into multiple group, and train seperately

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, dataset

If I have a training data, I divide them onto many group.

Then, for each group, I use a different neural network to train seperately/independently. Do you think this will be better than using a single neural network and train with ALL training data?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am wondering if I split the training data into several group, and then for each group, I fit a neural network to it. Would it have a higher prediction accuracy?

Comment: How would you make your predictions?